# Reading passed value in view asp.net mvc 3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I am new in asp.net mvc and learning. I have a view which pass a value to my method. This is the code below for passing that value:

```
  @Html.ActionLink("CPD Details", "Details1", new { id=item.ID, item.LastName})
```

Below is the method for my Details1. Some of the code has been omitted.

```
  public ActionResult Details1(int id, string LastName)

   return View()
```

Below is part of my Details1 view:

```
@model IEnumerable<onlineCPD.Models.cpd_certificates>
```

Please not that the value is coming from another model and there are independent i.e no mapping or relationship set. How do I display this passed value in my Details1 view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to view those variables in your view you should use ViewBag. Read this webpage for more information about ViewBag - [ViewBag in MVC 3](http://weblogs.asp.net/hajan/archive/2010/12/11/viewbag-dynamic-in-asp-net-mvc-3-rc-2.aspx)

Controller

```
public ActionResult Details1(int id, string LastName)
{
   ViewBag.Id = id;
   ViewBag.LastName = LastName;

   return View();
}
```

Your Details1 View

```
@model IEnumerable<onlineCPD.Models.cpd_certificates>

@{
   ViewBag.Title = "Details";
 }

 <p>
   id = @ViewBag.Id 
   <br/>
   Last Name =  @ViewBag.LastName
</p>
```

Go through this tutorial to learn more. [MVC-Music-Store Tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store)

Comment: Did you actually check values are going into the Details1 controller?

Comment: Yes there are going. The url link show the values. Please not that this value is from another model. And my model has something like this **@model IEnumerable<onlineCPD.Models.cpd_certificates>** not @model onlineCPD.Models.cpd_certificates

Comment: Are you saying the ViewBag is not working? I have updated my code to show exactly what should be in your View to show the values in the Viewbag.

Comment: Thanks. I had made typo error. Will ask get back to here when stuck somehwere. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You're welcome and remember to try out that MVC Music Store tutorial as more learning practice :)